# Rails Forms - Edit User Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an Edit User Form to amend the user details stored in my database but keep getting error. I have changed the form URL and tried changing it to a `method: :get` without much success.

**Edit User Form**

```
<%= form_with url: @user, :class => "user_sign_in_form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field "user[email]", placeholder: "email", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.text_field "user[username]", placeholder: "username", :class => "form_box"%>
  <%= form.text_field "user[password]", placeholder: "password", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit Action**

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Link to Edit User Form**

```
 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) %>
```

**Error Message**

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/58"
```

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: `resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :show]`

Comment: you need an update action as well...thats what the edit form is doing

Comment: I've added an update action but still have the same issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `model: @user` not `url: @user`.

```
<%= form_with model: @user, :class => "user_sign_in_form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, placeholder: "email", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.text_field :username, placeholder: "username", :class => "form_box"%>
  <%= form.password_field :password, placeholder: "password", :class => "form_box" %>
  <%= form.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

When you pass a model `form_with` will set both the action (`/users` or `/users/:id`) and method (`POST` or `PATCH`) depending on if the record has been saved. See [Resource Routing: the Rails Default](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

The `url:` option should really only be used if you have to override the conventional routes or if you have a form that does not wrap a model instance.

Also use `form.text_field :email` instead which will "bind" the input to the model attribute. Nobody likes having to refill an entire form from scratch because they missed some minor detail.

And on a side note [**do not** use placeholders instead of labels](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/) - its an aweful practice from both a useability and accessibility standpoint.

Comment: thanks! that seemed to sort it for the Edit form. Should this also apply to the New User form? When I make the same change to New User form get a routing error. It works with `url: users_path`

Comment: Yes - it also applies to the new form. Ideally you would use a partial to share the same form instead of repeating yourself. Its impossible for me to know why you're getting a routing error as I can't actually see your code. If you want an example if what your typical CRUD setup in rails looks like use `rails g scaffold thing name` to generate a scaffolded model, controller and views.  You can then clean up with  `rails d scaffold thing name`

Comment: You can also ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with the code for now.